# for-in loop VS in-operator

Tags: javascript, for-loop, prototype, enumeration, accessor

I consider myself a JS veteran but just now for the first time I have realised that the `for ... in` loop does something very different from the `in` operator:

```
"length" in []; // true
for (k in []) { if(k == "length") alert(); }; // k will never be "length"
```

**So this brings me to my question: why is the `in` operator at all present in the `for ... in` loop?**

Imho it is totally misleading, as it does different things. Also the notion that first the `for` operation makes the JS engine take all enumerable properties and then on that subset the `in` operator is used is imho wrong: simply because the `in` operator accepts *all* possible properties whether prototype or own, whether accessor- or data-properties. So how does it filter anything out if `for` has already reduced to enumerable object properties?

Comment: Did you mean to type this into an email to Brendan Eich?

Comment: The token `in` in the `for in` loop is not the `in` operator.

Comment: @Pointy: well perhaps he comes and answers this? :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Well I guess that sums it up. :)

Comment: ES6 also has new meaning  with *  for function* and yeid* . The spread operator is three dots, underscore becomes no arguments for arrow functions. map and Map are two completely different things and [+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]+!+[]] is the meaning of life. That's the nature of human readable syntax.

Answer (score 3):

> So this brings me to my question: why is the `in` operator at all present in the `for ... in` loop?

It isn't. The `in` token in the `for … in` loop construct is not an operator, just as much it is not one in the expression

```
x = {in: 5}.in
```

It's just one of the tokens that distinguishes a [`for ( … in … )`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements) from a [`for (…; …; …)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-statement) loop. Given that there is no `for (…)` statement, the role of the `in` token in a [relational expression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements) never collides with this.

Comment: I understand and I guess this is the most precise answer that can be given. I still find it misleading though as it would be very intuitive to think that the `for ... in` loop is based on the `in` operator and executes for exactly the cases where `in` returns true.

Comment: @BM: Well, both usages have something to do with properties, and I don't think there were many alternatives. That non-enumerable properties are not enumerated by a `for in` enumeration should be quite natural anyway.