# Precedence of "in" in Python

Tags: python, syntax, operator-precedence

This is a bit of a (very basic) language-lawyer kind of question. I understand what the code does, and why, so please no elementary explanations.

In an expression, `in` has [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html?highlight=precedence#operator-precedence) than `and`. So if I write

```
if n in "seq1" and "something":
    ...
```

it is interpreted just like

```
if (n in "seq1") and "something":
    ...
```

However, the `in` of a `for` loop has lower precedence than `and` (in fact it has to, otherwise the following would be a syntax error). Hence if a Python beginner [writes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33880344/699305)

```
for n in "seq1" and "something":
    ...
```

..., it is equivalent to this:

```
for n in ("seq1" and "something"):
    ...
```

(which, provided "seq1" is truthy, evaluates to `for n in "something"`).

So, the question: Where is the precedence of the for-loop's `in` keyword specified/documented? I understand that `n in ...` is not an expression in this context (it does not have  a value), but is part of the `for` statement's syntax. Still, I'm not sure how/where non-expression precedence is specified.

Comment: Precedence is only a concept for expressions. The "in" keyword there has no precendence, just like "for" and ":" don't.

Comment: `in` in case of the loop is not an operator, it has no precedence in that case. It's simply how Python parses a for-loop syntax.

Comment: Right, I understand that actually. But the parser has its own precedence rules for recognizing expressions, so there's still something to say.

Comment: BTW, even if precedence was different in the `if` case, this would not work, because `n in ("seq1" and "something")` is evaluated as `f n in "something"`. You probably meant `n in "seq1" + "something"`, which works just fine, as `+` has higher precedence than `in`

Comment: @tobias_k, I didn't write anything like this; the question was inspired by a beginner's use of the `for` loop variant (see linked question), which had me scratching my head for a moment since I do know that `in` has higher precedence in expressions. I'm still not sure what that code really intended...

Comment: When in doubt, you have two friends: ( and ). Use 'em.

Comment: Here's the [same question for JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33454474/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi nope, not the same question at all. That question is about how the two uses of the keyword are different (or call it two homonymous keywords if you prefer-- same difference). That's a given, no surprise there. The present question is which part of the language spec captures the difference in grouping precedence.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the context of a `for` statement, the `in` is just part of the grammar that makes up that compound statement, and so it is distinct from the operator `in`. The Python grammar specification defines a `for` statement [like this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for):

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```

The point to make is that this particular `in` will not be interpreted as part of *target_list*, because a comparison operation (e.g. `x in [x]`) is not a valid *target*. Referring to the grammar specification again, *target_list* and *target* are [defined as follows](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

```
target_list     ::=  target ("," target)* [","]
target          ::=  identifier
                     | "(" target_list ")"
                     | "[" target_list "]"
                     | attributeref
                     | subscription
                     | slicing
                     | "*" target
```

So the grammar ensures that the parser sees the first `in` token after a *target_list* as part of the `for ... in ...` statement, and not as a binary operator. This is why trying to write things very strange like `for (x in [x]) in range(5):` will raise a syntax error: Python's grammar does not permit comparisons like `(x in [x])` to be targets.

Therefore for a statement such as `for n in "seq1" and "something"` is unambiguous. The *target_list* part is the identifier `n` and the *expression_list* part is the iterable that `"seq1" and "something"` evaluates to. As the linked documentation goes on to say, each item from the iterable is assigned to *target_list* in turn.

Comment: Any insights on how this rule takes precedence over parsing `in` as part of the `expression_list`? Is it just left to right processing? Parser internals and "it would be a syntax error the other way around"? Something else yet?

Comment: @alexis: there is no `"for" target_list expression_list:` syntax, so it'd be a syntax error if interpreted that way. And `in` is a *binary* operator, so you need a left-hand side operator. `target_list` can't be it, because there is no `for expression_list:` syntax either.

Comment: @alexis: `in` is a keyword, so it can't be in `target_list`, and if there is an `in` in `expression_list` then it's completely independent of this syntax rule.

Comment: @alexis: the parser goes at tokens from left to right; by this time a new statement is required, `for` is found so a `for` statement is assumed; so until `in` is found, the tokens following `for` must match the `target_list` grammar rule. And only once valid `target_list` tokens have been processed and `in` has been found is an `expression_list` rule allowed to come into play. At no point is the `in` token seen as part of an expression.

Comment: Did you mean to say the `expression_list` is `"seq1" and "something"`, rather than just `"something"`? Sure, it evaluates to `"something"` because of the definition of `and`, but I wouldn't say that's what the expression "is".

Comment: @SteveJessop: that's a good point, I was taking the OP's example and jumping ahead somewhat. I'll edit the explanation so that it's clearer.

Comment: @ajcr This answer would be clearer if it included the definition of `target_list` and RemcoGerlich's observation that `in` cannot appear in a `target_list` (so the first `in` after `for` must be parsed as the "in" ilteral of the for-in construction rather than as part of either `target_list` or `expression_list`).

Comment: @zwol: thank you for the suggestion - I've edited my answer to try and address your points.

Comment: Thanks. So in the context of `for`, a `target_list` must follow, and this can never contain `in` **at the top level** (there might be one in a subscript expression, for example, but it will be parsed in a different context).

Comment: One quibble about "`in` cannot be interpreted as part of `target_list` because it is ... not a normal identifier": Expression-`in` is also a keyword, so this does not address how the disambiguation happens.

Comment: @alexis If you read through the full grammar of the language, I believe you will discover that a `target_list` cannot contain `in` at *any* level.  And it can't be processed as part of the `expression_list` because the parser only starts parsing an `expression_list` *after* it consumes the `in`.

Comment: @zwol, what makes you say that? A `target_list` consists of `target`s, a `target` can be a `subscription`,  a `subscription` contains an `expression_list` as the subscript, and an `expression_list` can of course contain a boolean expression with `in`.

Comment: I think that's a good point - I've edited to make it clearer that `in` *can* appear, but that Python won't treat a comparison operation on its own as *target_list* (as a comparison is not a valid target).

Answer (score 18):

The word `in` in a `for` loop is part of a *statement*. Statements have no precedence.

`in` the operator, on the other hand, is always going to be part of an expression. Precedence governs the relative priority between operators in expressions.

In statements then, look for the `expression` parts in their documented grammar. For the [`for` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement), the grammar is:

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```

The `and` operator in your example is part of the `expression_list` part, but the `"in"` part is *not part of the expression*.

The 'order' then is set in Python's grammar rules, which govern the parser. Statements are the top-level constructs, see the [*Top-level components* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/toplevel_components.html) (with stand-alone expressions being called [*expression statements*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#expression-statements)). Expressions are always part of a statement, giving statements priority over anything contained in a statement.

Comment: Well said. Treat the "in" in `for … in …:` as an homonym of the `x in [x]` expression: spelled the same, but not the same

Comment: @sleblanc, that they are homonyms is the starting point of the question. The question was how they get disambiguated, given that this also affects grouping. I think it's been covered by now...