# In-operator before and after for-in loops

Tags: javascript, object, for-in-loop, in-operator

I'm fairly new to Javascript and was trying to figure out exactly how the `for...in` loop works based on how the `in` operator works.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454474/for-in-loop-vs-in-operator) cleared up the confusion.

However, I'm now confused as to why the `in` operator returns `false` in all scenarios besides the very last one.

It looks like the `for...in` loop is creating the key keyTest in obj with the value of its last iteration.

Is my understanding correct?  Do `for...in` loops create key/values in the object they iterate over when used to go through all of an objects keys?

If so any help on understanding would really help.

```
var keyTest, obj = {}
keyTest in obj; // false
for(var keyTest in obj) { obj[keyTest] };
keyTest in obj; // false

obj = { a : 1, b : 2 };
keyTest in obj; // false
for(var keyTest in obj) { obj[keyTest] };
keyTest in obj; // true
obj[keyTest] // 2
```

Comment: `for-in` simply iterates over object keys, nothing more.

Comment: and `in` will return true if the object contains the given property. keytest and obj are both independent objects, neither one is a property of the other....

Answer (score 3):

> Do `for...in` loops create key/values in the object they iterate over when used to go through all of an objects keys?

No, but they assign keys to the iteration variable (`var keyTest` in your case). And that's why your examples produce the results you see.

```
// keyTest = undefined (initialisation of the hoisted variable)
var keyTest, obj = {} // keyTest === undefined
keyTest in obj; // keyTest === undefined
for(var keyTest in obj) { obj[keyTest] }; // `obj` is empty and `keyTest` stays what it is
keyTest in obj; // false // keyTest === undefined
```

```
// keyTest = undefined (initialisation of the hoisted variable)
obj = { a : 1, b : 2 }; // keyTest === undefined
keyTest in obj; // keyTest === undefined
for(var keyTest in obj) { obj[keyTest] }; // keyTest = "a", keyTest = "b"
keyTest in obj; // keyTest === "b"
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hoisting issue. There is no block-level scope in es5, so your `keyTest` variable is hoisted and declared at the beginning of the scope (function or global, it depends on where you run your code).

So `var keyTest` is not block variable, but scope variable, accordingly it refers to the same variable in every line of your code where it's used in this scope. And it's a reason why your `for` loop assigns last value of iteration to this variable.

---

If to talk about your example, the reason why you've got two different results is that in first example you have no keys in your `obj`, so `for` loop won't do any iteration, accordingly will not assign any value to your `keyTest` so it'll be still undefined.

---

But for example es6 has block-level variables. So if you change `var` to `let` (block-level variable declaration keyword) in your `for` loop and run this code in es6-compatible environment, you will have different output. Maybe this will help you to understand what is going on.

```
//es6 code
var keyTest;
obj = { a : 1, b : 2 };
keyTest in obj; // false
for(let keyTest in obj) { obj[keyTest] };
keyTest in obj; // false
obj[keyTest] // undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm now confused as to why the in operator returns `false`

`in` operator accepts 2 operands:

- left one is the key name to test
- and the right one is the object to test against

So for this code snippet

```
var keyTest, obj = {}
keyTest in obj; // false
```

the `keyTest` is `undefined` (you haven't initialised it with the value). So you're checking if `"undefined"` (it would be casted to string, since objects can only* hold string properties) is one of the `obj` object keys, which is not, hence `false`.

```
for(var keyTest in obj) { obj[keyTest] };
keyTest in obj; // true
```

Here it returns `true` because the `keyTest` variable holds the value of the latest iterated key after the loop is completed. So you're testing if an actual key is in the object.